# Create an avi video with opencv and python on a mac

Tags: python, macos, video, opencv, avi

this is my situation:

- Im trying to use opencv to generate an avi movie from some png images
- Using OpenCV 2.3.4, Python 2.7 on Mac OSX
- The program ends with no error, generates the file. But is not playable.

Here is the code:

```
    import cv 
    def make_video(nFrames):
        isColor = 1
        fps     = 1  #25 or 30, frames per second
        size = cv.GetSize(cv.LoadImage("canvas.png"))

        writer=cv.CreateVideoWriter("~/Documents/Workspace/Brief/video.avi",cv.CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'), fps,size,isColor)
#-----------------------------#Writing the video file:#-----------------------------
        for i in range(nFrames):    
            img = cv.LoadImage("canvas%d.png"%i) #specify filename and the extension
        cv.WriteFrame(writer,img) # add the frame to the video
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the DIVX codec on a platform that has neither a native encoder nor decoder for it. This won't work. Try using something simpler, like MJPG (Motion JPEG), instead.

Comment: Can you help me with some codec that is native from OSX? I google it , but I can't find it.

Comment: There's a way to include the codec inside my project so it become independent of platform?

Answer (score 0):

I found a list of codecs that are native on Mac OSX:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/QuickTimeCodecs

Now, it works very fine.