# Unable to write video using python and opencv2 on mac os x

Tags: python, macos, opencv, video

I am using mac os x 1.7.5 with python 2.7.5_1 and opencv 2.4.4_0 installed via macports. I seem to have all the latest dependent ports.

In my code, the `cv2.Videowriter()` is successfully created and opened which produces a 6kb .avi file but `videoFile.write(img0)` doesn't write anything into that file. I really am not able to figure out why the video stream isn't written to the file. Any insights?

My code is as follows:

```
import cv2
import cv

cv2.namedWindow("Original")

cap0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

codec = cv.CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X')
print codec

videoFile = cv2.VideoWriter();
videoFile.open('video.avi', codec, 25, (640, 480),1)

key = -1
while(key < 0):
    success0, img0 = cap0.read()

    cv2.imshow("Original", img0)

    videoFile.write(img0)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've tried these codecs and none of them worked: I420, AVC1, YUV1, PIM1, MJPG, MP42, MP4V, DIV3, DIVX, XVID, IUYV,FFV1, FLV1, U263, H264, ZLIB

I've also gone through all the [quick time codecs mentioned here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/QuickTimeCodecs)

Using ZLIB codec I get the error:

```
[zlib @ 0x7fb0d130a000] Specified pixel format yuv420p is invalid or not supported
```

Using H264 codec I get an error:

```
[libx264 @ 0x7fe423869600] broken ffmpeg default settings detected
[libx264 @ 0x7fe423869600] use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
[libx264 @ 0x7fe423869600] preset usage: -vpre <speed> -vpre <profile>
[libx264 @ 0x7fe423869600] speed presets are listed in x264 --help
[libx264 @ 0x7fe423869600] profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
```

I didn't understand what the above errors meant. I tried reinstalling ffmpeg to the latest version (1.2.2_0+gpl2) but my script still doesn't work. All the other codecs did not give any error.

I've even tried the file extensions of .mpg and .mkv with the above codecs. Sometimes I would get an error saying that the codec was not suitable for the file extension but when I didn't get error I would simply get the unreadable video file of a minuscule size.

Any help is much appreciated.

ps: I've already gone through the following SO questions which didn't solve my issue:

- [using opencv2 write streaming video in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045654/using-opencv2-write-streaming-video-in-python)
- [Writing video with OpenCV + Python + Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426637/writing-video-with-opencv-python-mac)
- [Create an avi video with opencv and python on a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066689/create-an-avi-video-with-opencv-and-python-on-a-mac?rq=1)
- [Python OpenCV, can't write a video (.avi) to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268740/python-opencv-cant-write-a-video-avi-to-file?rq=1)
- [Creating AVI files in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136989/creating-avi-files-in-opencv/1137034#1137034)
- [read/write avi video on MAC using openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756767/read-write-avi-video-on-mac-using-opencv?rq=1)
- [Python OpenCV 2.4 writes half-complete PNG video frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456727/python-opencv-2-4-writes-half-complete-png-video-frames)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to have been with the image size in the function `videoFile.open('video.avi', codec, 25, (640, 480),1)`

So I updated my script to include

```
size = (int(cap0.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
        int(cap0.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
```

And then accordingly changed `videoFile.open` to

```
videoFile.open('video.avi', codec, 25, size,1)
```

Then my script started working.

I've tried the codecs with fourcc: IYUV, I420, PIM1, MJPG, FFV1 and DIVX with file extension .avi

Each of the above codec worked with frame rates 16, 20, 25 and 30 except for PIM1 which seems to work only on 20fps and above.

Also,

- Codec with fourcc THEO worked with file extension .ogv
- XVID worked properly with file extension .mkv and though the .mkv container should work with any encoding I got a variety of weird results with other codecs.
- FLV1 with file extension .flv didn't work. It gave the error:

  `[flv @ 0x7f8414006000] Tag FLV1/0x31564c46 incompatible with output codec id '22' ([2][0][0][0])`
- FLV4 with file extension .flv didn't give an error but opencv's videowrite outputted an error "Could not update video file"

Of the codecs that worked with .avi file container, DIVX produced the smallest video file (~4Mb for 4 sec video) and IYUV produced the largest file (~160Mb for 4 sec video)

Note:

- `fps = videoCapture.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)` always returns 0.0 when capturing from webcam. It is a bug in OpenCV2.4.3 and OpenCV2.4.4
- I also found out that ffmpeg cannot grab images from Mac's iSight and FacetimeHD webcams the way it can from Windows and Ubuntu because designers at Apple have prohibited easy access to the mac's camera... what a shame!

References:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats

Answer (score 1):

Initially I was getting a 0kb video file. I changed the Codec from MJPG to iYUV. It worked for me. Python 2.7 and openCV 2.4.5.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourCC = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('i','Y','U', 'V'); # Important to notice cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC
size = (int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),   int(cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
out = cv2.VideoWriter("Test.avi", fourCC, 15.0, size, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get h264 working, install ffmpeg from the following link. Its quite a cumbersome installation but it ll get the encoder up and running.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu